# i Have a Computer with Old Configuration and want to install ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I have a computer with this configuration

Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 CPU 6300@ 1.86GHz 
RAM: 2GB
Hard disk : 500GB

Please suggest me which ubuntu is working good in my computer
i have ubuntu 16.4 with 32bits and 64bits

Please tell me which bit is better for my computer.

Thanks

Comment: is your computer 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: i don't have idea but i am using windows 7 32 bits

Answer (score 0):

If you try to install 64bit Ubuntu on a 32bit machine, you will receive an error message accordingly. 
A 64bit machine however will allow a 32bit Ubuntu installation.

As you said the machine currently uses Win7 32bits, more than likely you should use Ubuntu-32bit.

Comment: Hello Willem 

Thanks a lot . i have install ubuntu 14 32bit in my machine . ubuntu working fine. but i have another problem  skype is not working also you can say i am not able to install skype on it.

Comment: Please enter a new question for your Skype problem. Give details on what Skype version you installed and in what way you installed it; for example command line, Software Utility. Make sure to add screenshots of any errors.